# App Engine: How to redirect www request to non-www domain at DNS level

Tags: google-app-engine, redirect, dns

For a Java App on App Engine,

An App has been deployed at Custom Domain(example.com).

Site can be accessed from URL `http://example.com` but can't be accessed using `http://www.example.com`

How should the request for the www URL (`http://www.example.com/index.jsp`) should be redirected to non www URL (`http://example.com/index.jsp`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the same page where you added your custom domain, you select the second option on step 2 and add `www` into the  input box before your `example.com` then click `Add`. Then just follow the instructions in step 3.

[image: The page]
On your domain registrar, for the alias `www`, add the `name/value` `ghs.googlehosted.com` for type  `CNAME`. Doing all these steps will allow for the html at `http://example.com/index.jsp` to also be loaded at `http://www.example.com/index.jsp`.

Comment: This is a workaround to the original problem. I understood the user did not want to use www at all. This solution only instructs how to have both www.example.com & example.com working.

Comment: This does not answer the question. How to redirect from www to non www?